# Open source utility for comparing a C++ header file with its base

Tags: c++

I need to compare a C++ header file with a base version of the same file and check whether the file has modified or not. I need to get specifically like, function xxxx's prototype has modified.

Anybody have information about any opensource tool for this functionality?

If I give two .h files(one is the base file for comparison another is current version) as input, then I need to get a report with all the function prototypes, datatypes which is changed in the current version

Thanks in advance...

Comment: And the java tag is here because...?

Comment: Why is this question tagged in Java?

Comment: Would `diff` work for you?

Comment: In Windows `WinMerge` is a good tool. In linux -- `diff`, `vim-diff` and numerous others that can be googled in a minute.

Comment: What is the "base version"? Are you using version control?

Comment: I mean, the base version of the same file(.h) which must be compared

Answer (score 1):

1. You may use `Beyond Compare` This is commercial but 30 day trial.
2. You can use [compare plugin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/npp-compare/) with notepad++.
3. If you use `TortoiseSVN` client There is a option `Diff with previous version`.

If you need more details read [this](http://smashinghub.com/10-best-file-and-documents-comparison-tools.htm) article.

Comment: Upvote for beyond compare -- its diffs are the best that I have seen in any diffing tool so far.

Comment: I need to integrate the tool to CI and display which method is changed OR which datatype is changed. So if the tool can give a report with these informations, then it will be useful for me.

Comment: Actually all of these tools are capable to show you the changes in  line wise and file wise. But Those are not aware of functions and data types. Most of the file comparison tools consider your C++ files just as the text files.

Comment: Yes, if you came to know about any tool specifically for this purpose, then please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your problem isnt even language specific. From what i understand you need a tool like [this](http://winmerge.org/) maybe.

Comment: I need to integrate the tool to CI and display which method is changed OR which datatype is changed. So if the tool can give a report with these informations, then it will be useful for me.

Comment: @Albin like [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39138/TextDiff-A-Simple-C-Text-Compare-Application) ? This provides just basic text comparison

Comment: I am looking for not only text comparison, I need to know specifically any function prototype or datatype has modified. Please let me know if you find tool like this. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for [version control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control). [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org/) and [Git](http://git-scm.com/) are both great for your needs.

[`git diff`](http://learn.github.com/p/diff.html) will show you the differences introduced by commits.

Comment: I need to integrate the tool to CI and display which method is changed OR which datatype is changed. So if the tool can give a report with these informations, then it will be useful for me.

Comment: Yes, I am using Git and Gerrit. Jenkins is my CI

Comment: You could probably do something with `grep` and `git diff` in a bash script. Not sure if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: If I give two .h files(one is the base file for comparison another is current version) as input, then I need to get a report with all the function prototypes, datatypes which is changed in the current version

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it, but [CodeCompare](http://www.devart.com/codecompare/) claims to be a diff tool aimed at comparing code, not just text.
There's a free version, but I think you can try the full version for a few days.